# What is the syntax for HTML5 Drag and Drop Dropzone

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

so what's the syntax for the 'Dropzone' attribute for receiving elements?

I can get an element to be draggable, but I can't declare a dropzone, and some of the JS I've seen that enables this is incredibly hard for me to understand...

I know that the dropzone needs to be something like this:

```
<div id="something" dropzone="move f:image/png"></div>
```

But what happens when I want to move another div element here...? What's the f: type?

Answer (score 0):

f:image/png means that this div element will accept file with type image/png as drag and drop data.
If you drag another div element on this dropzone nothing would happen. You can read about this here http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#dnd